# How to count elements in nested lists

Tags: python

How do I count the number of elements in a nested list?

I want to transform:

```
myList = [[0],[1,4,5,8],[5],[2,3,9],[7,7]]
```

into:

```
myList = [1, 4, 1, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Python gives you the `map` function which allows you to apply a function to each element in a list. You could simply write:

```py
result = list(map(len, myList))
```

Answer (score 1):

With only 2 dimension:

```py
[len(sub_list) for sub_list in myList]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [len(l) for l in myList]
[1, 4, 1, 3, 2]
```

Another way is to use `map`:

```
>>> list(map(len, myList))
[1, 4, 1, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a two dimension list like you have shown you can use the following code

```
res = [len(x) for x in myList]
```

or you could use a map function as follows

```
res = list(map(len, myList))
```